Linking lib files in rust (CbcSolver.lib)
I try to make a rust program that solves a mip problem using good_lp. It fails when cargo tries to call link.exe.
Platform: Visual Studio Code on Win11.
Error message:
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "C:\\Users\\jdpet\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustcnX6XoN\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\jdpet\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Projekt\\Rust\\Assign\\assign\\target\\debug\\deps\\assign.19ekypdsjbrzh1zd.rcgu.o" <... Cut long line ...>
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'CbcSolver.lib'


warning: `assign` (bin "assign") generated 3 warnings
error: could not compile `assign` (bin "assign") due to previous error; 3 warnings emitted

I have located a directory containing CbcSolver.lib, but I haven't found out how to tell the linker where it is.
Question:
How do I make the location of CbcSolver.lib known to the linker? Should this be done in Cargo.toml, in some VSCode configuration or in some linker configuration? I am very new to Rust if that is not already apparent above.

You need to provide the directory address to the linker with the /LIBPATH option, as described at Linker options.

I should have written that I call cargo from powershell.I tried to set env:RUSTFLAGS and got another linking error (a lot of missing symbols) instead.

Sorry, but I have no experience of cargo, I can only suggest that you see if the documentation helps. See The Manifest Format - The Cargo Book

Original problem not solved but I got around it by switching to another solver, Clarabel, that is written in Rust.

It should be included in build.rs.
